# DPF (Diesel Particulate Filter) and Turbo: Golf TDI Bluemotion(hybrid)

Tags: vw, diesel, turbocharger, catalytic-converter, fuel-filter

I have a problem with my 2012 Golf TDI Bluemotion. The DPF and turbo need to be replaced. The replacement costs about R65 000 SA Rands. Is this common with this TDI blue motion engines or it's my driving?

how can a turbo and DPF fail at same time, are they interlinked?

Please help

Comment: That's about $4000 to $5000 in case anyone was wondering.

Comment: Please consider adding what the specific issue is with the DPF/Turbo, and/or HOW you know there is an issue.

Answer (score 4):

The DPF or Diesel Particulate Filter is part of the exhaust system the Turbocharger pulls it's power from the exhaust system so it in conceivable that a blocked DPF filter could stall the turbocharger causing damage.  Also, a failed turbocharger could dump lots of oil into the DPF which would be equally damaging.

We have a 2012 1.6 TDI Bluemotion Golf and have had no problems with either the Turbo or DPF but I guess that doesn't help you.

Answer (score 3):

The DPF is basically a catalytic converter for a diesel engine. I wouldn't say it's necessary that both of these things fail at the same time, but it's possible. I will assume you do lots of short trips rather than regular long trips?

At any rate, the DPF needs to periodically heat up and stay hot for a long period to burn off excess deposits. A nice long road trip would be a good way to do this.

Being a fellow South African, the first thing I would suggest is taking the car to an RMI-approved workshop that is NOT a VW dealership. (Most) Agents have a reputation for overcharging and even recommending repairs that are unnecessary. *(compare a R45 000 repair quote vs R17 000 from an independent using the same OEM replacement parts)*. Have your car inspected by a third party and see what they say. On that note, a DPF really shouldn't fail after only 3 years. You see this more often in cars that are older than 7 years or so. The car should still be under warranty, so explore that possibility before you sell a kidney.

I wouldn't expect the replacement of a turbo + DPF to cost more than R20 000 *max*.

Comment: It is sad to see VW service departments are crap the world over ... such a great car ... it's just sad.

Comment: It's not just VW. I told the MD of General Motors South Africa that I refuse to buy another one of their cars because of how rude and shady their people are.

Comment: What I was getting at is VW Service problems seem to be systemic worldwide. I've not heard of a good VW Service department ... *ever*. I've heard of plenty of good GM, Ford, Mercedes, BMW, etc., ones ... but never a VW one. I'm sure there are localized issues with *every brand*. It's just VW seems to be the worst.

Comment: That's kind of sad. Luckily I'm too poor to afford a new car, so I've always had my cars serviced by an independent AA accredited workshop (if you don't have a maintenance plan, why use the expensive and dodgy agents?).

Comment: Turns out Subaru South Africa isn't all bad. If anyone was interested.

Comment: Just to add... I have twice encountered a very kind and helpful VW Service station, but I was there with a very old VW and maybe them being nostalgic helped. But still I prefer VW over any other brand for the ease of repairs.